# set DllPath value of oracle.dataaccess.client settings at runtime

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config, odp.net, oracleclient

I have add

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
   <settings>
       <add name="DllPath" value="<application_path>\bin"/>
   </settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

to my web.config.

Can it be possible to set DllPath value on runtime..

Comment: You can copy necessary DLLs into `bin` folder of your webapp.

Comment: I have the dlls but it does not affect if there is another installed client on machine. Because it refer another path with registry key. So there is only one way to overwrite it on as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the existing setting which can be done from config. The issue is a current setting getting picked up from a file such as machine.config

You can achieve this using config such as this, place is in you app.config or web.config

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
           type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

The above config will remove an current references and replace the entry to Version 2.112.3.0 which will be picked up from your bin folder.